# How to convert struct to NSItemProviderWriting in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsobject

I have a struct model and convert that struct into NSObject also convert the resulted nsobjectitem to NSItemProviderWriting for drag & drop concept.

I'm using swift 4.2 & Xcode 10.1
fist I'm converting that struct into an array and then it cast it to NSObject.
then I'm giving the nsobject item to NSItemProvider

```
guard let summaryItem = [self.summarys[indexPath.row]] as? NSObject else {
    print("not parse to nsobject")
    return []
}

let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: summaryItem as! NSItemProviderWriting)
let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
dragItem.localObject = item
return [dragItem]
```

the output of the following code will be produced an error and the error is " Could not cast the value of type 'Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray to 'NSItemProviderWriting'."

my expectation is to avoid that crash on proper format

Comment: What exactly do you want to drag/drop? Types that conform to `NSItemProviderWriting` include `NSString`, `NSAttributedString`, `NSURL`, `UIColor` and `UIImage`. Try converting your struct to one of those types. What is your struct representing anyway?

Comment: I'm using collection view and I have to implement drag & drop. in that cell, I represent some strings from getting through API (using decoder, so I'm using a struct). Type not conform NSItemProviderWriting on struct and so it converts to nsobject and place here `NSItemProvider(object: summaryItem as! NSItemProviderWriting)`.

Comment: @Nijosh Did you ever solve your issue? I've been looking for a straightforward clear answer for what I am doing as well. Articles on the topic  I've found so far are't very helpful.